# Collection of list using linq in where condition in MVC controller

Tags: c#, linq

I having one collection of list, in that list I need to get values by where statement, the condition of where statement is `status = 137` and `status = 224`. By this I need to get the result in a collection  of list in C# MVC

```
List<MyActiveBooking> objList = Vendordetails.GetActivebooking(objpartentid.PARENTID);
objList = objList.OfType<MyActiveBooking>().Where(s => s.STATUS.Equals(137) 
                                                    && s.STATUS.Equals(224)).ToList();
```

Comment: And what exactly isn't working? You don't need the `OfType` cast as your collection is already of type `MyActiveBooking`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe wanted to get both where status is 137 OR 224? Also you dont need to cast your objList to specific type since it already is one.

```
var objList = Vendordetails
              .GetActivebooking(objpartentid.PARENTID)
              .Where(s => s.STATUS.Equals(137) || s.STATUS.Equals(224))
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

How can a Status be 137 and 224 at the same time? use or - ||

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this -

```
List<MyActiveBooking> objList = Vendordetails.GetActivebooking(objpartentid.PARENTID);
 objList = objList.Where(s => s.STATUS == 137 || s.STATUS == 224).ToList();
```